# Django Models - Reverse Foreign Key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

These two classes have Foreign Key to each other and class OrderRow is representing a row which belongs to an Order, I want to know is there any way to set "rows" attribute inside class Order to show a list or query-set of all related order rows by calling it on an object or instance of class Order?

```
class OrderRow(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    **rows = models.ForeignKey('OrderRow', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_rows')**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have ForeignKey in `OrderRows` with `related_name="rows"`. Like this:

```
class OrderRow(models.Model):
    # rest of the fields
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rows')
```

Then you can use:

```
order = Order.objects.first()
for order_row in order.rows.all():
    print(order_row)
```

For more information, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/).